# Capturing multiple pictures

Tags: android

I try to create an Android camera app which should capture multiple pictures.The length of delay between two subsequent pictures must be 0.2sec. camera.takePicture(null, null, null, PictureCallback) function captures subsequent pictures in a second delay. How can i do this process faster?

Comment: Lowering the resolution of the picture may help some. Processing the previous picture's results in a background thread -- so you can use the main application thread to set up for the next picture -- may help some, if you are not doing that already. But the performance is determined mostly by camera hardware. Camera hardware varies in quality, and lower-quality hardware will tend to be slower. There is nothing that you can do about that.

Comment: Please see my answer to a similar post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42592531/how-to-make-user-click-5-pics-and-display-it-in-different-image-view-in-android/42598225#42598225

I show the steps you need to take to capture multiple pictures from the camera without returning to your app between each picture.